# Turn on 2 LED's at a particular time in C mongoose os

Tags: c, timer, esp8266, led, mongoose-os

So I have an espressif chip connected to 2 LEDs, and mongoose os runs on it

I would like to get time from the internet/computer and make the led's turn on at a particular time.

eg. at 10:00 turn on/off led 1 connected to pin 2 and at 16:00 turn on/off led 2 connected to pin 3 in C.

Comment: I assume you mean [this Mongoose-OS](https://mongoose-os.com/), and not the [MongoDB object modeling tool](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) that the `mongoose` tag is about? Created new tag and edited your question with the new tag.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Add wifi setup to your `mos.yml` so it can connect to your wireless AP:

```
config_schema:
  - ["wifi.sta.enable", true]
  - ["wifi.sta.ssid", "MyAP"]
  - ["wifi.sta.pass", "Passwd"]
```

Step 2: Add these to your `mos.yml`.  Leave off `rpc-uart` if you have no intention of making rpc calls over UART.

```
libs:
  - origin: https://github.com/mongoose-os-libs/sntp
  - origin: https://github.com/mongoose-os-libs/crontab
  - origin: https://github.com/mongoose-os-libs/rpc-service-cron
  - origin: https://github.com/mongoose-os-libs/rpc-service-config
  - origin: https://github.com/mongoose-os-libs/wifi
  - origin: https://github.com/mongoose-os-libs/rpc-uart
```

Step 3: Add crontab handlers for LED on and LED off:

```
enum mgos_app_init_result mgos_app_init(void) {
  /* Set LED GPIOs as outputs */
  mgos_gpio_set_mode(YOUR_LED_GPIO, MGOS_GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);

  /* Register crontab handler - LED OFF */
  mgos_crontab_register_handler(mg_mk_str("ledoff"), ledoff, NULL);

  /* Register crontab handler - LED ON */
  mgos_crontab_register_handler(mg_mk_str("ledon"), ledon, NULL);

  return MGOS_APP_INIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Step 4: Add callbacks:

```
void ledoff(struct mg_str action, struct mg_str payload, void *userdata) {
  mgos_gpio_write(YOUR_LED_GPIO, 0);
  (void) payload;
  (void) userdata;
  (void) action;
}

void ledon(struct mg_str action, struct mg_str payload, void *userdata) {
  mgos_gpio_write(YOUR_LED_GPIO, 1);
  (void) payload;
  (void) userdata;
  (void) action;
}
```

Step 5: From Web UI or UART:

```
call Cron.Add '{"at":"0 0 10 00 * *", "action":"ledon"}'
call Cron.Add '{"at":"0 0 16 00 * *", "action":"ledoff"}'
```

See https://github.com/mongoose-os-libs/cron as a reference for the syntax of cron expressions on mgos.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174327/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-j-turn-on-2-leds-at-a-particular-time-in-c-mongoos).

Comment: How to incorporate the step 5 from within the main.c ?

Comment: Calling RPC calls from within your code is non-trivial.  First you need to look up which callback function `add_handler()` uses for `Cron.Add`, which in this case ultimately ends up being `add_or_edit_job()`.  Then you need to figure out how to replace the calling args, or re-write the guts of that function yourself.  Sometimes it can be a bit of work.

Comment: @AndyJ : ideas on hwo to implement this with the help of buttons and 2 leds ? -- Press flash button 1 led 1 goes on at a time, press flash button 2, led 2 goes on, press flash button 3- just displays the current time.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the solution is missing:

Step 2a: In main.c add:

```
#include "mgos_crontab.h"
```